# the graph in the view is not displayed - Chart.js Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

The graph in the view is not displayed:

```
 <canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"
            chart-series="series" chart-click="onClick"></canvas>
```

test-controller.js:

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('app.test')
            .controller('TestController', TestController);


        function TestController( $scope,  $timeout) {

            initialize();

            function initialize() {

                $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
                $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
                $scope.data = [
                    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                ];
                $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
                    console.log(points, evt);
                };

                // Simulate async data update
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.data = [
                        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
                        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                    ];
                }, 3000);

            }

        }
    })();
```

index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"> 
</script>
```

I use the example
https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js#example

I do not know why the graph is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same way, make sure that **`angular-charts`** and **`chart.js`** should have the correct versioned library references.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```

**DEMO**

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js'])
  .controller('myController', [function() {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.socialChart = {
      options : {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            stacked: true
          }]
        }
      },
      type: 'StackedBar',
        labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
        series: ['FACEBOOK', 'GOOGLE', 'TWITTER', 'INSTAGRAM'],
        colors: ['#ED402A', '#F0AB05', '#A0B421', '#00A39F'],
        data : [
      [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
    ]
    }
  }]);

})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multi Slot Transclude</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
  <canvas id="outreach" class="chart chart-bar" chart-labels="ctrl.socialChart.labels" chart-data="ctrl.socialChart.data" chart-series="ctrl.socialChart.series" chart-colors="ctrl.socialChart.colors" chart-options="ctrl.socialChart.options"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added no graph is displayed

Comment: check the demo above

Comment: adding this line: `.module('App.test',  ['chart.js'] )` the project breaks down. How to pass the value of ['chart.js'] to the model differently? I added the contents of the controller, but the chart does not display (without a line of code `.module('App.test',  ['chart.js'] )`